# CakePHP query returning different results then running directly in sql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**GOAL**

I am attempting to return all `features` and all associated (if any) `features_user_types` where the user_type_id = ?.

So for example, I have 2 `features`. I want both to be returned along with all associated `features_user_types` as long as the user_type_id = 2. If there is no matching `feature_user_type` then it should return `feature` anyway.

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

Example Output: WHERE user_type_id = 2

```
"features": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "features_user_types": [
      {
        "id": 79,
        "feature_id": 1,
        "user_type_id": 2,
        "position": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "features_user_types": []
  }
]
```

**ACTUAL RESULTS**

However, currently it is returning all associated features_user_types despite their id not equaling 2.

$query->toArray() Output:

```
"features": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "features_user_types": [
      {
        "id": 79,
        "feature_id": 1,
        "user_type_id": 2,
        "position": 3
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "features_user_types": [
      {
        "id": 72,
        "feature_id": 2,
        "user_type_id": 1,
        "position": 9
      }
     ]
  }
]
```

**DATA STRUCTURE**

Table Structure:

```
features
-id

features_user_types
-id
-feature_id
-user_type_id
-position

user_types
-id
```

CakePHP Association Definitions:

FeaturesTable:

```
$this->belongsToMany('UserTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'feature_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'user_type_id',
        'joinTable' => 'features_user_types'
]);
$this->hasMany('FeaturesUserTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'feature_id'
]);
```

UserTypesTable:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Features', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_type_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'feature_id',
    'joinTable' => 'features_user_types'
]);
$this->hasMany('FeaturesUserTypes', [
    'className' => 'FeaturesUserTypes',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_type_id'
]);
```

FeaturesUserTypesTable:

```
$this->belongsTo('Features', [
    'foreignKey' => 'feature_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('UserTypes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_type_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

**QUERY OBJECT**

I have a query builder in my cakephp app that is creating the following sql according to the `$query->sql()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   Features.id AS `Features__id`, 
   Features.created AS `Features__created`, 
   Features.modified AS `Features__modified`, 
   Features.name AS `Features__name`, 
   Features.description AS `Features__description` 
FROM features Features 
LEFT JOIN features_user_types FeaturesUserTypes 
   ON (FeaturesUserTypes.user_type_id = 2 
      AND Features.id = (FeaturesUserTypes.feature_id))
```

**MySQL**

However, if I copy and paste this directly into MySQL I get the results that I expect, all `features` with only `featurs_user_types` matching the id are returned.

Actual Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM features Features 
LEFT JOIN features_user_types FeaturesUserTypes 
  ON (FeaturesUserTypes.user_type_id = 2 
    AND Features.id = (FeaturesUserTypes.feature_id))
```

MySQL Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ID (feature id)|ID (feature_user_type_id)|feature_id|user_type_id|position|
| 1             | 79                      | 1        | 2          | 3      |
| 2             | NULL                    | NULL     | NULL       | NULL   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**CODE**

AppController:

My AppController is very generic but built to take it paramters from URLs to generate and execute sql queries. It is a rather large file so instead I went through it with a debugger and recorded any lines that $query was altered and filled in the variables to make it more obvious.

```
$key = 'FeaturesUserTypes.user_type_id';
$value = 2;

$model = $this->loadModel();
$query = $model->find('all', ['fields' => $this->getFields()]);
$query->contain(['FeaturesUserTypes']);
$query->leftJoinWith('FeaturesUserTypes', function($q) use ($key, $value) {
   return $q->where([$key => $value]);
});
$query->distinct();
$results = $query->toArray();
```

Any idea on what could be happening? I am running CakePHP 3 and PHP 5.6.10. Thanks!

Comment: The query will return **all** records from the `features` table, not just the matching ones. It is unlikely that this query pasted into MySQL would return the matching records only. If you wanted the matching records only, then change left join to inner join.

Comment: The query has a check for id in the join, it absolutely works as expected in MySQL. And the results in no way match CakePHP's results. This type of query works in CakePHP for other models just fine which is why I think it may have something to do with the relationship type.

Comment: Nope, it returns all results in MySQL as well. See the answer I provided below.

Comment: I just ran it and it returned 1 feature, the one with the features_user_types matching the id. I need it to return all 10 features including the one matching features_user_types' user_type_id.

Comment: Then I do not understand your question at all. Pls reword it to make it more clear. Also, provide the way you perform the query. The same query is not going to return different results, unless the underlying data is different.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [**`contain()`**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain)? Please try to add reproducible code examples to your questions, it's hard to understand what exactly the problem is when one can't see what exactly you're doing.

Comment: Maybe showing us the code that builds and executes the query will be useful.

Comment: I have updated the question with as much detail as possible and relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `hasOne` and `belongsTo` associations, which are using joins in the main query unless explicitly configured otherwise, `hasMany` and `belongsToMany` associated data is always being retrieved in a separate query.

Note that `sql()` will always only return the main query, not the possible additional queries used for eager loading associations! If you need to know about the additional queries, check [**DebugKits**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html) SQL log panel. So what this means, is that the query that you're testing manually, is not what the ORM will actually use to retrieve the associated data.

What you're looking for is passing conditions to contain, ie remove the `leftJoinWith()` (unless you need the associated data in the main query too for further SQL level operations), and attach the condition callback to the `FeaturesUserTypes` containment instead:

```
$query->contain([
    'FeaturesUserTypes' => function($q) use ($key, $value) {
        return $q->where([$key => $value]);
    }
]);
```

And for anyone who reads this, make sure that `$key` does not hold user input, otherwhise this would be an SQL injection vulnerability!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Eager Loading Associations Via Contain > Passing Conditions to Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > HasMany Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations)**

Comment: This appears to be the solution (running automation now). However, I do have to leave the `leftJoinWith()`, otherwise I get an error that 'FeaturesUserTypes.position' on does not exist (used in the `order()`) when I call `toArray()`. So ultimately the line changes from `$query->contain([$function]);` to `$query->contain([$join => $function]);` where `$function = function($q) use ($key, $value) {
   return $q->where([$key => $value]);
});`. Thank you mucho!

Comment: @jrquick I see... `order()` isn't in your example, but I'll add a hint in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is *usually* wrong to do filtering in the `ON` clause:

```
FROM a
JOIN b ON b.x = 2 AND a.z=b.z
```

Move the filtering to the `WHERE`:

```
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.z=b.z
WHERE b.x = 2
```

Also, don't use `LEFT` unless you *want* the nulls for "missing" rows in the 'right' table.

I don't know your data, but it seems like `DISTINCT` is not appropriate.